# IF...ELSE in R Assistance

Tags: r, if-statement

I am trying to write an If...Else statement in R and I am running into some difficulties. I have a data set that has 20 years of data and the values of VariableA need to be adjusted based on the specific year they are in (VariableB). I tried using an If...Else statement but I keep getting:

`VariableA    VariableB    Multiplier   VariableC
     100          1998         1.4           140 
     100          1998         1.4           140
     100          1999         1.7           170
     100          1999         1.7           170
     100          2000         2.0           200
     100          2000         2.0           200`

*Error: unexpected '}' in " }"*

The code that I have been trying to get to work is below:

```
Data <- function(DMG, YEAR){
if(YEAR = "1998"){
Data$TotDmg2017 <- Data$DMG * 1.433988335
}
}
```

I am not sure if this is the correct code to be using or if this is the most efficient way of doing this. I am unfamiliar with loops and If...Else statements so any assistance would be most appreciated.

Comment: Try changing `YEAR = "1998"` to `YEAR == "1998"`

Comment: You could try something like this `Data <- function(DMG, YEAR){
  df$TotDmg2017 <- ifelse(YEAR == "1998", DMG* 1.433988335,  DMG)
  return(df)
}` where `df` is your data frame (df = data)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach using tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(~varA, ~varB, ~multiplier, ~varC,
              100,1998,1.4,140,
              100,1998,1.4,140,
              100,1999,1.7,170,
              100,1999,1.7,170,
              100,2000,2.0,200,
              100,2000,2.0,200
              )

df <- df %>%
  mutate(varA = ifelse(varB == 1998, varA * 1.433988335, varA))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
   varA  varB multiplier  varC
  <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl>
1  143.  1998        1.4   140
2  143.  1998        1.4   140
3  100   1999        1.7   170
4  100   1999        1.7   170
5  100   2000        2     200
6  100   2000        2     200
```

Thanks to @gregor for reminding me the need to explain the code.

I would like to preface by saying that I am merely presenting an alternative approach to the question at hand. If this approach is not merited, please feel free to ignore it.

The `mutate()` command is the grammatical way of creating a column within the tidyverse. In essence, I'm creating a new column called varA which will essentially replace the existing varA column.

In the original request, you've used `if(){}` and `else(){}` statements. Both are valid. For simplicity, I've used the `ifelse()` function. This function is  built into base R and I find it a bit easier to read. Personal preference.

The syntax for `ifelse()` is `ifelse(test, yes, no)` (as according to the help page). Basically, if your test condition is true, then whatever you put in the "yes" argument will execute, otherwise the "no" argument will execute.

In the example I provided, I simply used a similar test condition that you applied. If the varB value happened to equal 1998, then it would take the existing value in varA and multiply it by 1.4339.

Comment: The `tidyverse` is distracting here. OP has a problem with `if(){}else{}` when they probably should be using `ifelse()`. You correct their mistake without explaining it, but and wrap it in `mutate()` also without explanation. This would be a much better answer if you (a)  explained why to use `ifelse()` instead of `if(){}else{}`, and (b) separated that from any `dplyr` recommendations you want to make.

Comment: @Gregor thank you for taking the time to remind me of the need to elaborate on my solution. I've edited my proposed solution to include a bit more details to help clarify my proposed approach. I do understand the OP used if() and else(). However, I felt strongly that an alternative approach may be useful. I will leave it up to the OP to determine if the approach I presented is a distraction and not useful.

Comment: `ifelse` is certainly better than `if` in this case! To make `if(){} else()` work one would need to wrap it in a for loop and it would be really inefficient compared to `ifelse()`. This is what needs explaining. The key difference here is that `if()` checks one condition at a time, while `ifelse()` is vectorized and can operate all at once on a vector of conditions. (Much improved with edits, btw)